# Enable Table in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, css-tables

I'm new to this website I need your help.

I recently bought real space Wordpress theme.

When I try to add table in Wordpress pages, the table border is not visible. I already add border value 1.

I try few plugin also, still no use.

Please check below style.css, I don't know how to fix it. Please help me check this .css file.

Download .css file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/fu0kz8h93zwmpgv/Table.css?dl=0

Comment: I have seen your css, where most of the places, table has  "border:none" . Can you please send the website live link then it will be easy to solve problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response. Im using WordPress. Can you able to fix using .css file ?

Comment: ya I can fix please let me know the live link of your website.

Comment: ok you made two tables with CSS border is coming. and without CSS border is not coming. Now what is your question , what exactly you want?

Comment: Ok, Actually i dont want to write CSS border script every time when i need to create table. so i want to declare in main style.css in word press.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.

In your wordpress theme bootstrap is there, so need to change anything.

Just you have to add **class - "table table-bordered"**

whenever you make table add given class

See given below snippet code for more clarification

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Testing</td>
<td>Testing</td>
<td>Testing</td>
<td>Testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Testing</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Testing</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Testing</td>
<td>Testing</td>
<td>Testing</td>
<td>Testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Testing</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Testing</td>
<td></td>
<td>Testing</td>
<td>Testing</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working well.. Its really helpful page stackoverflow.com. Thank you guys.